# Low pass sequencing has been reported to detect common variants. How low can one go and get reliable data? Is 2X pass sequencing analysis possible?

Tags: ngs, gwas, gatk, coverage

I would like to use [low pass sequencing](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3276614/) to replace a [genotyping chip](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2019.00544/full) to be able to detect [variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_(biology)) up to 0.1 % [allele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) frequency in available population data. What is the minimum [depth](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrg3642) I can opt for to retain the [confidence](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8188283/) of [base calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_calling)? Can [GATK](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us) be used to analyse this data?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good idea - low pass sequencing has shown to be better than genotype arrays for things such as GWAS or QTL mapping.

The primary way of processing low-pass sequencing data is to use imputation - partciularly methods such as GLIMPSE or QUILT and a large reference panel such as the HRC or TopMed in order to refine the genotype calls.

This is a figure from [the GLIMPSE paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41588-020-00756-0.pdf?proof=t%C2%A0) showing how you can retain variants of different frequencies at different levels of sequencing depth.

[image]

And a similar image from [the QUILT paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41588-021-00877-0.pdf):

[image]

You might also want to check out some of the methodology in this paper http://m.genome.cshlp.org/content/31/4/529